# The most efficient way to backup changes for directory with lots of small files

Tags: file-management, backup, file-synchronization, synchronization, filesystems

What is the most efficient way to backup for this situation:
900 thousand files, 30 GB total, most of the files are extremely small - few KB.
Sometimes some files change transactionally, most of the files not.
We need to have archives of exact dicrectories while it is updated or the whole tree of the files.
What can be used here for the most efficiency? Some filesystem, source control version or some snapshot mechanism?
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use the new version of Syncback pro (V9) 
https://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbpro.html which has it seems a new "Delta-Copy" feature :

"*Probably the most requested feature has now been added. **You can now copy and store just the changes to files.** SyncBack Touch (for Windows) has also been updated to allow delta-copy over the network, so the destination file is a complete file.(...)
With huge files, like Virtual Machines and databases, you may want to save storage space by just copying and storing the changes and not the entire file. SyncBackSE and SyncBackPro now support delta-copy via the existing versioning feature. We've also added delta-copy to SyncBack Touch, where only the changes are transmitted over the network, and the entire file is rebuilt on the other end.*"
https://www.2brightsparks.com/v9/

Comment: Looks goo, but expensive. Then again, @Alexander did not use the [tag:gratis] tag, or state a budget ;-)